# How to check if data is getting processed in Spring Integration or sitting idle

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

This is regarding Spring integration(SI) Application where in my case there are many endpoints present. So usually when data enters into this application, it takes about 60 sec to get processed completly.
I am now trying to build shutdown mechanism for this application which will do following things :-

1. It will first stop ingestion layer endpoint (in my case a kafka listener), so that no more message will enter into application
2. It will then wait for 60 secs before getting shutdown. So that existing message gets processed.

But this wait time is hardcoded and i want to check if application is processing any data or not. If yes then wait for 30 secs and then check again. If no data are getting processed then shutdown the application.
Kindly let me know if there are any ways which i can check if data are present in any of the SI endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no hooks like this in the out-of-the-box components. And probably it is even not possible to implement that since all the component in the framework are stateless.

Now tell me, please, what makes you think that you need to implement your own shutdown mechanism. Why the regular `ApplicationContext.close()` is not enough for you?

See more about lifecycle in the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-nature

With that on board the framework indeed stops inbound endpoints first to not let external data to enter the application while it is in the shutdown state. Then it stops all other internal endpoints to stop processing their incoming messages. But all on-the-fly messages are still processed. The application context is not done if there is something executing.

If that still not enough for you, I'd suggest something like an `AtomicInteger activeCount` as a global bean. You `incrementAndGet()` it when the message is emitted by your mentioned Kafka listener. When you done processing the message in the end of flow your call its `decrementAndGet()`. And when your custom shutdown function is in progress, you just check the number of that `activeCount.get()` to be sure that it is `0` to kill your process gracefully.

But again: we don't need all of that because the standard `ApplicationContext.close()` covers us.